# How to set custom layout for those notifications which will be shown when app is in background?

Tags: java, android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, remoteview

I implemented the firebase cloud messaging (FCM) service in my app and I get notifications with my custom layout but just when the app is in the foreground and the reason is clear, It is because of existing `setCustomContentView(myContentView)` in `onMessageReceived` and we all know that `onMessageReceived` handle notification just when the app is in the foreground.

Now, I'm going to know is there a way to set the same custom layout for the notifications which will be shown when the app is in the background?

Comment: Use _data_ payload instead of _notification_ payload which works for both foreground and background.

Comment: use data object instead of notification object

Comment: And how to set a custom layout? can you give me some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise to modify server code to receive data onMessageReceived in both foreground and background and ask sender to send only data payload without notification.

Here I have removed notification payload.

```
{"to":"[add your token]","data":{"title":"Working Good","body":"[add your message]"},"priority":"high"}
```

Answer (score 2):

FCM has two messages types: when your app is in the background.

- Notification message: 
  [image]
- Data message:
  [image]

  1. Notification message: the notification is delivered to the device’s system tray, not onMessageReceived
  2. Data message: always, the notification is delivered to onMessageReceived
     [image: As image]

so, You should send a format is Data Message to handle notification in onMessageReceived when the app is background or foreground